# How to link experimental::simd in clang

Tags: clang, simd, clang++, c++-experimental

I am having trouble linking `std::experimental::simd` operations in `clang++` on MacOS Ventura.  Here's my minimal failure:

```
#include <experimental/simd>

using std::experimental::simd;

int main()
{
    simd<float> x;
    x = -x;
}
```

I am compiling with:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++20 minimal.cpp
```

And I get the linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::experimental::parallelism_v2::simd<float, std::experimental::parallelism_v2::__simd_abi<(std::experimental::parallelism_v2::_StorageKind)1, 4> >::operator-() const", referenced from:
      _main in minimal-d275bc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Is this just missing from my standard library, are there other linker flags that I need to include, or what?  Thanks.

Clang version:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
```

Comment: What's your clang version? It seems to work without additional linker flags using clang 12.0.1 or gcc 11.1 (or later): https://godbolt.org/z/8P5MeKGbd

Comment: @chtz, `Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)`  hmm, thanks